# umbrella framework with cocoa-pods dependencies using Aggregate target

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods, aggregate

I'm trying to create an umbrella framework with pods 'GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection' and 'lottie-ios'. [I have followed this tutorial](https://medium.com/@andreamiotz/ios-umbrella-framework-with-cocoapods-57d2d3c2daa9) but run script is throwing me some errors like

> error build: error: accessing build database "/Users/AMacbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjKnowFace-clxihwqrnrwcxqgqlogoujtwmlpf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/build.db": disk I/O error

After some research, [I found this solution on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38353271/how-to-build-an-aggregate-target-for-a-dynamic-library-which-contains-dependenci/38394066#38394066), and I was able to create the Framework (named: ObjKnowFace) but with some errors like **no such module 'Lottie'**. When I import this Framework in some other project, I get this error

> Could not build Objective-C module 'ObjKnowFace'

Any help regarding this would really be appreciated. ThankYou :)

[image]